# Div always facing the screen inside a rotateY div

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-animations

This is my code:

html

```
<div id="back">
   <div id="right_text">TEST</div>
   <div id="left_text">TEST2</div>
</div>
<div id="mid"></div>
```

css

```
#mid {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: rotate linear 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:-125px;
    position: static;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
#back {
    width:auto;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-animation: rotateY linear 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: static;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateY {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg)
    }
}
#right_text {
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
#left_text {
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bXhL8/

As you can see, both text-divs face their back to the screen when they are not on their side of origin. i want both of them to always stay the same and just "hang on" to the rotation of my back-div.

my question would be if that is possible in css alone or if id need js for it.

Comment: ok I've got an idea on my own, maybe it works with counter-rotating both div divs. ill try that now and keep you posted.

Comment: ok the text is now always written left-to-right, which is a semi-success. the two div divs however do not always face their front to the screen, is this because my #back div is not a 3d object in which rotation is displayed the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your css

```
#left_text, #right_text {
 -webkit-animation: rotateY linear 5s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/bXhL8/2/)

**Update**

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/bXhL8/3/)

Comment: I've done that in my first update (well sort of, i used a second animation) but it doesn't give me the desired effect. the text should always face the front, no matter in which stage of the animation.

Comment: checked update, but now text1 and text2 don't switch sides. ill try a different approach with some pseudo-rotation, thanks for the help so far i will post an update later.

Comment: @poochy maybe you can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/bXhL8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

here is my new bit of code. its not a perfect circle yet, because i just added 4 frames to my @keyframes. im thinking about making a actual circular rotation and adding a skew() element to the whole circular function / to my whole body, don't know if that will work though.

thanks for your help!

html:

```
<div id="right_text">
    <div id="right_text_text">TEST</div>
</div>
<div id="left_text">
    <div id="left_text_text">TEST2</div>
</div>
<div id="mid"></div>
```

css:

```
#mid {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: rotate linear 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    margin-top: 105px;
    margin-left: 210px;
    position: static;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

#right_text_text {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: downupright linear 8s infinite;
}

#left_text_text {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: updownleft linear 8s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes downupright {
    0% { left: 490px; top: 150px;}
    25% { left: 245px; top: 100px; z-index: -10;}
    50% { left: 0px; top: 150px;}
    75% { left: 245px; top: 200px; z-index:10;}
    100% { left: 490px; top: 150px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes updownleft {
    0% { left: 0px; top: 150px;}
    25% { left: 245px; top: 200px; z-index: 9;}
    50% { left: 490px; top: 150px;}
    75% { left: 245px; top: 100px; z-index: -9;}
    100% { left: 0px; top: 150px;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bXhL8/4/